# 8 hours stay at frankfurt

Tags: layovers, pakistani-citizens, frankfurt, canadian-residents

I am a Pakistani passport holder, and a permanent resident of Canada, with PR card. Travelling via Frankfurt by Air Canada. Can I visit the city during this 8-hour layover or does it require any formality?

Comment: Travelling from/to where? I suspect you can only transit without a visa if you stay airside but to get an accurate answer we need to know your origin and destination points.

Comment: As a guess the OP is flying between Pakistan and Canada (or the other way). But it would be useful if this was explicitly stated.

Comment: Since you have Canadian PR, you can transit airside in Frankfurt without a visa. To leave the airport, you need a Schengen visa.

Answer (score 3):

As a Pakistani citizen you would need a Schengen Visa to enter Germany. As a Canadian resident you can apply for it at a German consulate in Canada, but you still need a Visa. https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/germany-visa/canada/